# Problem with adding event listener in loop

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a list of elements and I'd like to add a click event to each one that will call a function and pass it an index of a list. In the case below I'm defining `itemIndex` as 0 and incrementing it each loop. When the click event is called the index it uses is `3` (number of loops +1) instead of the number of the loop. How can I solve this problem?

```
let itemIndex = 0;
itemList.forEach(item => {
    const itemFragment = document.importNode(this.itemTemplate.content, true);

    //add click event
    itemFragment.querySelector('.part').addEventListener('click', () => {
        loadItem(itemList[itemIndex]);
    });
    //append product to body row

    itemTarget.appendChild(itemFragment);
    itemIndex++;
});
```

Comment: [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the index argument in `forEach`. Currently, you are incrementing the same outer variable on each iteration, so each event handler accesses the same value.

```
itemList.forEach((item, itemIndex) => {
        const itemFragment = document.importNode(this.itemTemplate.content, true);
        
        //add click event
        itemFragment.querySelector('.part').addEventListener('click', () => {
            loadItem(itemList[itemIndex]);
        });
        //append product to body row
    
        itemTarget.appendChild(itemFragment);
    });
```

In your case though, you don't actually need the index itself but the item on each iteration, so just pass `item` to `loadItem`.

```
itemList.forEach(item => {
        const itemFragment = document.importNode(this.itemTemplate.content, true);
        
        //add click event
        itemFragment.querySelector('.part').addEventListener('click', () => {
            loadItem(item);
        });
        //append product to body row
    
        itemTarget.appendChild(itemFragment);
    });
```